# TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA on IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm working on changing the cipher specifications on a number of web servers that I manage, to avoid the BEAST/BREACH/CRIME kerfuffle that everyone's talking about.

On our LAMP hosts, I simply upgraded to OpenSSL 1.0.1 and Apache 2.4, and used these cipher specs:

> SSLCipherSuite
>   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA256:RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!MD5:!NULL

Which function as I want -- compatible clients generally get the cipher spec from the topic, and hopefully in the future TLS 1.2-compatible clients will get the GCM suites, and everything fails pretty gracefully.  However, we have some very important ASP.NET apps running in IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2 (fully patched), and the group policy "SSL Cipher Suite Order" does not seem to support this.

In Server 2008 R2, in the group policy for cipher suites, it lists supported ciphers.  Apparently it only supports GCM ciphers for `ECDHE_ECDSA`, not `ECDHE_RSA`.  Only CBC is supported for `ECDHE_RSA`.  Also, there is no listed support for combining `ECDHE_RSA` with RC4.

Am I missing something, or is there a good workaround?  All I can think to do is proxy it through a host which *does* support the encryption I want, but that is not desirable for a number of reasons.  Am I stuck using regular `RSA-RC4-128-SHA`?  Or if I disable HTTP/TLS compression, and take the performance hit, can I use `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256` or similar safely?

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, I'm pretty new to this sort of thing.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, BREACH/CRIME are from a different category of vulnerabilities since they can be patched without modifying the Ciphersuite list.
As for BEAST, the exact definition is CBC Ciphers + SSL3 or TLS1.0, but actually, most SSL testers consider it _patched_ if you have TLS1.1 or TLS1.2 (https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/09/10/is-beast-still-a-threat). There are so few ciphers in SSL3/TLS1.0 outside of CBC/RC4 that you will end up breaking up everything.